# Are Secured Credit Cards offered in Hong Kong?

Tags: hong-kong, secured-credit-card

My relative will be moving from Canada (that does have Secured Credit Cards) to Hong Kong, but  has no credit in Hong Kong and hopes to start building her credit. Thanks.

Canada and the US have them. Please read [this](http://www.greedyrates.ca/blog/top-credit-cards-for-bad-credit-canada-unsecured-secured-credit-card/) to learn what a Secured Credit Card is.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/HongKong/comments/54uqn4/are_secured_credit_cards_offered_in_hong_kong/ sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Credit Card is not a necessity in HK. You can survive with 100% cash.

Credit Cards are easily approved, provided that you have 3 month of local employment history and applied for the suitable card. Go to https://www.moneyhero.com.hk/en/credit-card/all and sort by Annual Salary ascending. Get those with 40000/48000 income requirements.

There is no exact equivalent for Secured Credit Card in HK.
There is Prepaid/Debit but it won't help you build credit.

There is a situation where if you put Time Deposit for a few years they would give you credit card even if you have 0 income.